# Book where main character comes out of stasis bubble

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book in the 80s and am unable to think of the name.  The story begins with the main character coming out of a stasis bubble.  These bubbles were of different sizes and some were huge, covering cities even.  At some point in time (through flashbacks) some of the bubbles even became dislodged from the Earth and floated out to space, carrying all contents with them.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144878/story-where-dome-is-erected-freezing-people-in-time-one-person-gets-trapped-ou

Answer (score 16):

This is probably *Marooned in Realtime* by Vernor Vinge, or just possibly one of the shorts that were incorporated into the final form of the novel.  The bubbles were called "Bobbles" and were originally thought to simply insulate the inside from the outside, forever -- thus anyone caught inside a Bobble was believed dead.  It wasn't until a lifetime later that the first Bobble burst and revealed the interior to have changed not at all in the intervening half century.

Once that was known, and the cause/effect of how long a Bobble would last could be controlled, they became widely used for things like shielding, long-term storage, and time/space travel (a trip to another star might take centuries -- but with Bobbles, only the time your system needs to check conditions and re-Bobble would be perceived; the trip would seem to take a second or so).

The actual novel follows a small group of people who, due to Bobbles, missed the "singularity" in which humankind vanished from the Earth.

Comment: I think *The Peace War* is the book he's looking for - *Marooned in Realtime* was a sequel.

Comment: You might be right, but I don't recall *The Peace War* starting with someone coming out of a Bobble; rather it centered around the "escape" of the technology from government/military secrecy to "anyone with a modern computer can make these".  Bobbles collapsing hadn't been discovered yet in *The Peace War*.

Comment: I haven't read it since the 80s, but I believe the main character was a woman  who emerged from a bobble which was created right at the beginning of the 'war'.  She had been in a space shuttle.

Comment: Actually she might not have been the main character - I think the main character was the scientist who was her former lover, and who hadn't been bobbled.  The book definitely starts with her bobble suddenly popping and her shuttle crashing.

Comment: Yes.  That shuttle was Bobbled in *The Peace War* and the Bobble was heavy enough to crash to the ground.  *Marooned in Realtime* begins at or near the time the shuttle Bobble collapsed.

Comment: I reread both novels a few days ago. Both use bobbles, and _The Peace War_ does start with a pilot coming out of stasis; bobbles could be of any size. But bobbles in space were extensively used in the sequel, _Marooned in Realtime_. 
The two books were later combined under one set of covers as _Across Realtime_.

Comment: Hmm.  I might be conflating a shorter work, prequel to *The Peace War* then -- and I'm not at home where my books are.

Comment: *The Peace War* was first published as a serial in *Analog*, and has a (very brief) pre-Bobble introduction.

Comment: @mark And that's where I read *The Peace War* -- at the local library, which means before 1979.